# How to draw the chart like RangeBar MS chart with ["DrawSideBySide"] = "false" option?

Tags: winforms, gantt-chart, livecharts

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hxkkB.png)

I want to create a live chart using WinForms and LiveCharts, but I haven't been able to find any examples on the internet. Therefore, I'm reaching out here for help :(.

My data points consist of DateTime Start - DateTime End pairs, and I have multiple series, each represented by a different color, as shown in the attached picture. I need to draw data points for each series according to the index on the Y-axis (001, 002, 003). I have attempted to use GanttPoint, but it seems that GanttPoint doesn't allow me to set an index for drawing.

Code by any chart lib with nice view